# ffmpeg: extract video between two PTS values using a filter

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to extract video and generate a timelapse between two PTS values ("make a timelapse of all video between 8am and 6pm").

The [original video comes from a network camera](https://github.com/imaginator/system/blob/master/salt/motion/files/record-video.service#L38-L43) and contains a `-initial_offset` equivalent to the unix wallclock:

```
ffprobe  -i camera01-20200312-092453.mkv -show_frames -select_streams v:0 -print_format flat | grep pkt_pts=

Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/srv/video/netcams/archive/recordall/camera01-20200312-092453.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 440024:24:42.97, start: 1584001479.967000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 2048x1536, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1k tbn, 1 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
DURATION        : 440024:24:42.967000
frames.frame.0.pkt_pts=1584001479967
frames.frame.1.pkt_pts=1584001480967
frames.frame.2.pkt_pts=1584001481967
frames.frame.3.pkt_pts=1584001482967
frames.frame.4.pkt_pts=1584001483967
frames.frame.5.pkt_pts=1584001484967
...
```

I have tried `-ss` and `-t` but these seem to assume the file starts at 0.

Some background: I use the `-initial_offset` to ensure that each frame's PTS is set to the unix timestamp:

```
... -f segment                      \
        -segment_time 86400         \
        -initial_offset "$(date +%%s.%%N)" \
        -segment_format matroska    \
        -strftime 1                 \
        "camera01-%%Y%%m%%d-%%H%%M%%S.mkv" \
```

My current approach is to look for videos in the last day, concatenate them and then aim to extract video between two known times:

```
find /srv/video/netcams/archive/recordall -newermt $(date +%Y-%m-%d -d '1 days ago') -type f -print | \ 
  sed -e "s/^/file '/"  -e "s/$/'/" | \
  ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0  -protocol_whitelist file,pipe,crypto -i - -c:v libx264 -r 30 -filter:v "trim=start_pts=1584001492967:end_pts=1584001514967000,setpts=PTS/500," -preset ultrafast
```

What's the best way to go about this? I guess I'm missing something to do with the filter ordering?

Comment: The concat demuxer will necessarily start its emitted streams with timestamp 0. For all subsequent files, their initial timestamp is set to be smooth with the last timestamp of the earlier file. To maintain absolute timestamps, you need to use a streaming container like MPEG-TS and then use the concat *protocol* with -copyts flag. However, MPEG-TS can only timestamps as large as 95443s. Larger timestamps get rolled over.

Comment: I suggest you loop through files to identify the segment containing the starting in timestamp and its relative offset in that segment. Same for outpoint. Then set the inpoint and outpoint directives for those segments. and comment out all entries for segments before and after in the concat list.

Comment: Good to know about the timespamp size limitations. Presumably ffmpeg -i camera01-20200312-092453.mkv  -filter:v|trim=start_pts=1584001483967:end_pts=1584001500967" out.mkv should work though?

Comment: After adding `-copyts`

Comment: So this works - I was just impatient with the command - seems seeking through an 8GB file for specific PTS takes a bit of time. Thanks again @gyan